# Загрузка скрипта по клику

Tags: jquery, jquery-form

Предположим, есть кнопка button с id=btn и пустой `<div id="emptydiv"> </div>` на странице. По нажатию на кнопку загружается новый блок div на странице.

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
var str = "<div id="out"> </div>";
$('#emptydiv').html(str);
});
```

Затем я хочу уже в новый div с id=out вывести скрипт.

```
var scr = "<script>...</script>";
$('#out').html(scr);
```

Все это должно произойти по клику на button. Сейчас у меня скрипт загружается только при втором клике, при первом нет. Будто не находит #out на странице, как дождаться появления блока на странице и затем уже в него вывести?

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){ /* g̶o̶v̶***k̶o̶d̶*/ console.log('content loaded') });`

Comment: так не помогло, пробовал

Comment: Где находится код, вставляющий скрипт?

Comment: "загружается только при втором клике" - при втором клике на что?

Comment: на кнопку) Первый клик по сути загружает div, а второй клик уже скрипт в данный div. А хочется, чтобы все произошло по 1 клику

Comment: @StenFord Если Вам охота валять дурака, я, конечно, этому помешать не могу. На какую кнопку? В вопросе нет этой кнопки. Чем Вас не устраивает пример из моего ответа.

Comment: Да, я выводил именно также) Но ниже есть комментарий, в котором уже много было сказано, оказалось дело в задержке. Мой скрипт был один в один как ваш

Comment: @StenFord Нажмите кнопку "Выполнить код" в ответе. А потом на кнопку "Click". Там нет никакой задержки.

Comment: В данном случае все хорошо, но я не говорил, что мой скрипт делает console.log(123). Там сторонний скрипт, как оказалось дело в нем. Но я уже разобался, спасибо всем за помощь)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что Вам мешает вставить его сразу, в момент создания элемента #out? Просто вставьте текст скрипта прямо внутрь div
Но если нужно именно так - тогда ниже добавьте `$('#emptydiv').find('#out').html(str);`
Сразу после создания div#out

Суть в том что div#out это динамически созданный элемент и jquery не может его найти в Dom дереве

Comment: Если скрипт сразу вставить в div, тогда по клику загружается div, а скрипт загружается только по 2-ому клику

Comment: То, что Вы написали, не имеет никакого отношения к сути. jQuery все может.

Comment: find тоже не помог, опять же по 2-ому клику) В общем я пытался в nav-tabs из двух вкладов в одной вкладке вывести комменты из вк, в другой комменты с сайта. Ничего кроме как забыдлокодить это через тупой вывод, я не придумал умнее. Весь скрипт пихаю в строку и вывожу, но комменты почему-то именно комменты вк не хотят сразу загружаться. а по второму клику только) Причем сам nav-tabs я также вывожу через jquery. Хочется, чтобы комментарии загружались по клику, кому не нужны комменты, для них не лишний раз не загружать скрипты, а выводить кнопку для их загрузки

Comment: Быть может) У меня часто были проблемы с динамически создаными элементами. Нас рассудит только автор вопроса)

Comment: Слишком мало информации. Возможно дело во времени загрузки этих комментариев и ассинхронноси? Я бы дал очень вредный совет попробовать поставить таймаут (но это только для теста), а если подтвердится- поставить необходимую проверку (без таймаута)

Comment: Я думал про таймаут, но не решился его ставить) ибо я не могу точно знать время загрузки скрипта, сегодня он загрузился за секунду, завтра за доли секунды) заставлять каждый раз ждать загрузки нехороший вариант, но я попробую сейчас

Comment: Так я и предлагаю просто тест. Естественно нужно найти событие, а не таймаут. Какой скрипт или блок нужно подождать и повесить на это нужное Вам событие.

Comment: Я слегка подправил вывод, сейчас при задержке в 100мсек не работает, в 200мсек выводит) Дело все-таки в задержке вывода скрипта. Скрипт быстро выполняется, выводит div  и тут же ищет его и пытается в него вывести комментарии, не находит. Если поставить задержку в 200мсек когда выводится див, то норм выводит с 1 клика

Comment: Комментарий появляется из скрипта вк на который вы не можете повлиять? Если да- отследить какой блок создаёт скрипт вк и поставьте вместо таймаута интервал. Например 10 мили секунд. И каждый раз проверяйте наличие блока. Когда блок появится сбрасывает интервал. Таким образом вы убережете пользователей от лишнего ожидания и сможете не вмешиваться в работу внешнего скрипта. Это Вам небольшой лайфхак.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо) Очень помогли

Comment: Я жду отметки про решенный вопрос)

Answer (score 1):

В общем как-то так..
А вообще не советую так делать, лучше функцией вызвать после клика..

```js
$('#btn').on('click',function(){
  var block = '<div id="out">Govnokod</div>';
  var code = '&lt;script>console.info("govnocod activeted")&lt;\/script>';
  $('#emptydiv').append(block);
  $('#emptydiv').find('#out').append(code.replace(/&lt;/g, '<'));
});
```

```css
#out {background: red; min-height: 20px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn">Go govnokod</button>

<div id="emptydiv">
bla-bla-bla
</div>
```